# what is used more in the work place, text editors or IDE's?

Tags: text, ide, text-editor

Hey guys I'm looking for advice and guidance. 
Text editors or IDE in general which one is better? Which one is used more in the work place?

Answer (score 0):

IDEs and Text editors both have a solid role in the work place. Some frameworks have IDEs that tremendously boost productivity.

If you create iOS natie apps, XCode is your tool. If you are doing ASP.net MVC sites then Visual Studio is your best friend. If you have to compile an IDE is a faithful companion.

For web developers, there is an entire gamut of lightweight IDEs (or super text editors) that provided many productivity tools like syntax highlighting, code completion or bindings for build and execution environments.

Even still, a robust text editor like Notepad++ or Text Wrangler are great tools for quick file edits, script composition and log viewing.

Then there are the folks that do everything in VI...